# Pipes are getting stuck--no other solution on stack overflow working

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pipe, pathos

(UPDATED) I am building a module to distribute agent based models, the idea is to split the model over multiple processes and then when the agents reach a boundary they are passed to the processor handling that region. I can get the processes set up and working with no communication, but cannot get the data to pass through the pipes and update the model segment on the other processor.

I have tried the solutions on stackoverflow and built a simple version of the model. As soon as I put in a model object into the pipe the model hangs (it works with python standard data types). The simple version just passes agents back and forth.

```
 from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessPool
 from pathos.helpers import mp
 import copy



 class TestAgent:

 "Agent Class-- Schedule iterates through each agent and \
  executes step function"

 def __init__(self, unique_id, model):
      self.unique_id = unique_id
      self.model = model
      self.type = "agent"

 def step(self):

       pass 
       #print ('     ', self.unique_id, "I have stepped")

class TestModel:

   "Model Class iterates through schedule and executes step function for \
   each agent"

   def __init__(self):
       self.schedule = []
       self.pipe = None
       self.process = None

       for i in range(1000):
           a = TestAgent(i, self)
           self.schedule.append(a)


   def step(self):


       for a in self.schedule:
           a.step()

if __name__ == '__main__':

   pool = ProcessPool(nodes=2)

   #create instance of model
   test_model = TestModel()
   #create copies of model to be run on 2 processors
   test1 = copy.deepcopy(test_model)
   #clear schedule
   test1.schedule = []
   #Put in only half the schedule
   for i in range(0,500):
       test1.schedule.append(test_model.schedule[i])  
   #Give process tracker number
   test1.process = 1
   #repeat for other processor
   test2= copy.deepcopy(test_model)
   test2.schedule = []
   for i in range(500,1000):
       test2.schedule.append(test_model.schedule[i])
   test2.process = 2

   #create pipe
   end1, end2 = mp.Pipe()

   #Main run function for each process
   def run(model, pipe):

      for i in range(5):
          print (model.process)#, [a.unique_id for a in model.schedule])
          model.step() # IT HANGS AFTER INITIAL STEP
          print ("send")
          pipe.send(model.schedule)
          print ("closed")
          sched = pipe.recv()
          print ("received")
          model.schedule = sched



   pool.map(run, [test1, test2], [end1,end2])
```

The agents should switch processors and execute their print functions. (My next problem will be synchronizing the processors so they stay on each step, but one thing at a time.)

[image]

Comment: I'm the `pathos` author.  It will help people respond to your question if (1) you make a simplified version of this code that doesn't use `mesa` but still produces your error, and/or (2) you also post your traceback if you have any.  It seems it just hangs, is that correct?  That's typically what might happen if you have a pipe blocking, and no information is ever sent to it. I also suggest you try a `SerialPool` and a `ThreadPool` to see if you can identify it as an issue of something interactive with the `ProcessPool`.

Comment: Your example run if you remove the `pipe.close` after your send in python3. I don't understand the error you have. Could you be a bit more specific? (also, your example have some indentation error)

Comment: Gentleman, thanks. I got the small version working (removing pipe.close()), and updated the code above to remove mesa dependendencies. I then applied those same fixes to my actual model and was still having the same issues. I was able to recreate those issues by increasing the number of agents to 1000. It just hangs, requires a ctrl-break and I get: from multiprocessing/connections : line 287 _in_send_bytes [ov.event], False, INFINITE --full traceback above

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. I was exceeding the pipe buffer limit in python (8192). This is particularly true if the agent holds a copy of the model as an attribute. A working version of the above code, which passes the agents one at a time is below. It uses Pympler to get the size of all the agents.

```
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessPool
from pathos.helpers import mp
import copy

# do a blocking map on the chosen function

class TestAgent:

"Agent Class-- Schedule iterates through each agent and \
executes step function"

   def __init__(self, unique_id, model):
       self.unique_id = unique_id
       self.type = "agent"

   def step(self):
       pass 


class TestModel:

   "Model Class iterates through schedule and executes step function for \
   each agent"

   def __init__(self):
       from pympler import asizeof 

       self.schedule = []
       self.pipe = None
       self.process = None
       self.size = asizeof.asizeof


       for i in range(1000):
           a = TestAgent(i, self)
           self.schedule.append(a)


   def step(self):


       for a in self.schedule:
           a.step()

if __name__ == '__main__':

   pool = ProcessPool(nodes=2)

   #create instance of model
   test_model = TestModel()
   #create copies of model to be run on 2 processors
   test1 = copy.deepcopy(test_model)
   #clear schedule
   test1.schedule = []
   #Put in only half the schedule
   for i in range(0,500):
       test1.schedule.append(test_model.schedule[i])  
   #Give process tracker number
   test1.process = 1
   #repeat for other processor
   test2= copy.deepcopy(test_model)
   test2.schedule = []
   for i in range(500,1000):
       test2.schedule.append(test_model.schedule[i])
   test2.process = 2

   #create pipe
   end1, end2 = mp.Pipe()

   #Main run function for each process
   def run(model, pipe):

      for i in range(5):
        agents = []
        print (model.process, model.size(model.schedule) ) 
        model.step() # IT HANGS AFTER INITIAL STEP
        #agent_num = list(model.schedule._agents.keys())
        for agent in model.schedule[:]:
            model.schedule.remove(agent)
            pipe.send(agent)
            agent = pipe.recv()
            agents.append(agent)
        print (model.process, "all agents received")
        for agent in agents: 
            model.schedule.append(agent)

        print (model.process, len(model.schedule))



   pool.map(run, [test1, test2], [end1,end2])
```

Mike McKerns and Thomas Moreau --Thanks for the help you put me on the right path.